# How to get the current Jenkins pipeline StepContext

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a step in a pipeline that pulls objects from the context and uses them. However, I need to access those objects outside of the steps to feed into different steps, and the second step doesn't expose it.

```
stage() {
  steps {
    script {
        def status = waitForQualityGate()
        // Use the taskId
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `waitForQualityGate()` call only returns a boolean, so I can't access it there.

I could instead manually initialize the step, like so:

```
 script {
    def qualityGate = new WaitForQualityGateStep()
    def taskId = qualityGate.getTaskId()
 }
```

but the `taskId` is null. If I try to run the start methods manually on the step:

```
script {
    def qualityGate = new WaitForQualityGateStep()
    qualityGate.start().start()
    def taskId = qualityGate.getTaskId()
}
```

It fails with the message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: you must either pass in a StepContext to the StepExecution constructor, or have the StepExecution be created automatically

The `WaitForQualityGateStep` has the info I need, but I can't initialize it without having a StepContext (which is an Abstract class). How can I get one from the pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have no idea how to manually get a step context to manually execute a step, but in case anyone else finds this by trying to get information out of the Sonar plugin, this is how I got the task ID that I needed.

```
def output = sh(script: "mvn sonar:sonar", returnStdout: true)
echo output  // The capture prevents printing to console

def taskUri = output.find(~'/api/ce/task\\?id=[\\w-]*')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the variable before the pipeline and in the step just set its value. This way the variable is visible across the pipeline.